# Ubuntu touch - OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vpn, openvpn

Is there something available or on the horizon (network settings or an app) to use OpenVPN with Ubuntu touch?

My secondary solution would be to switch to read-write (although I'd hate loosing over the air updates) and apt-get install openvpn, plus probably some more configuration to route all web traffic through the connection. Would you see any general problem with that?

Cheers
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ubuntu phone/tablet images now have OpenVPN support. The configuration is a bit arduous, being a phone, but it is now usable on the images by default.

Answer (score -1):

Currently I am not aware of any other option than installing OpenVPN client via apt-get.

You can turn the read-write mode off if you need an OTA upgrade, but you probably need to reinstall OpenVPN again after the OTA. Saving the install steps to a small bash script would probably make this a reasonable hack until somebody creates a snap to install via the Touch GUI. However since the OpenVPN Ubuntu client is basically a plugin to network-manager this might not be that straight forward.

Comment: Making the root partition writable is not generally advised, as any changes to it may be wiped in future updates, or you will no longer be able to update the system image, potentially leaving your phone without security updates. However, VPN support is now included in the phone images.